# Pandas read_csv import column with multiple values as list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a .csv file containing several columns of which one contains multiple values:

```
"column1";"column2";"column3";
some_string; 1 ; 1,2,3,4 ;
```

Now, I would like to import the file using pandas read_csv:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')
```

This obviously leads to the issue that the multiple values get imported as a single string object. Is there any way I could import these values as a list or an array that I could even call a single value in that cell? That would be tremendously helpful!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can convert the string to a list as post-load step. using `df.column3.str.split()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this after loading the data, you would need a `lambda` function:

```
df['column3'] = df['column3'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split(","))
```

Check type of cell, this gives list:

```
type(df.iloc[0,2])
```

Inspect the length, this is 4:

```
len(df.iloc[0,2])
```

Select an element in your list:

```
df.iloc[0,2][0]
```

Turn the list elements in integers:

```
df['column3'] = df['column3'].apply(lambda x: list(map(int, x)))
```

Inspect type:

```
type(df.iloc[0,2][0])
```

Comment: That's great and it works! The only thing I've observed using `type(df.iloc[0,2][0])` that the elements within the list are indeed stored as a string not an integer. Can I do something about that as well? I mean for calculations, I could simply call it with `int(dfSimp.iloc[0,2][0])` but the value itself would remain as a string.

Comment: @nic: it is my pleasure! I have added a line of code that turns the elements into integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `converters` argument of [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to pass a function for the specified col:

```
>>> pd.read_csv(s, sep=';', usecols = range(3), 
                converters = {'column3':lambda x:x.split(',')})

       column1  column2         column3
0  some_string        1  [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
# or,
>>> pd.read_csv(s, sep=';', 
                converters = {'column3':lambda x:x.split(',')}).dropna(1)
       column1  column2         column3
0  some_string        1  [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```